# Powershell: Passing variable into scriptblock within function

Tags: powershell

So take this code:

```
function populate([string] $group)
{
    $listbox.items.clear()
    Get-ADGroup -filter {cn -like "*$group*"} | 
        foreach {$listbox.items.add($_.DistinguishedName)}
}

$go.Add_Click(
{
    populate -group $text.text 
})
```

I'm trying to take the variable `$group` and pass it to `{cn -like "*$group*"}` but I can't get it to work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = "*$group*"
Get-ADGroup -filter {cn -like $pattern} ...
```